# Unity.MVC5 The type IUserService does not have an accessible constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm using Repository pattern and using

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(x =>
         x.Namespace != null && (x.Namespace.Contains("TM.Service") ||
          x.Namespace.Contains("TM.Repository"))
    ),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.PerResolve
 );
```

Every thing works at first, but after changing cshtml file or even a js file at run time, (Start debugging or Start without debugging) I get "The type IUserService does not have an accessible constructor." error! 
That's driving me crazy, because that was working before changing a js or cshtml file.

When this error occurs, restarting webapp doesn't work or even building project. The only way to get webapp running again is to Rebuild Solution.

btw, my repositories and services are in separate projects.

UPDATE:

```
public class UserService : BaseService<User, IUserRepository>, IUserService
    {
        public UserService(IUserRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {
            this.Repository = repository;
        }

}


public interface IUserService : IBaseService<User>
    {

    }

public interface IBaseService<TModel> : IDisposable where TModel : BaseEntity
    {
        object Create(TModel model);
        object Edit(TModel model, string[] blackFields = null, string[] whiteFields = null);
        object Delete(int id);
        IEnumerable GetAll();
        IEnumerable GetGridData();
        IEnumerable<TModel> FindBy(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate);
        int Count(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate);
    }


public interface IUserRepository : IBaseRepository<User>
{
}


public interface IBaseRepository<TModel> : IDisposable where TModel : BaseEntity
    {
        TMContext Context { get; set; }

        IDbSet<TModel> Entity { get; set; }

        IQueryable<TModel> All { get; }

        IQueryable<TModel> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] includeProperties);

        TModel Find(int id);

        IEnumerable<TModel> FindBy(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate);

        int Count(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate);

        void Insert(TModel model);

        void Update(TModel model, string[] blackFields = null, string[] whiteFields = null);

        void Delete(int id);

        void Save();

    }
```

and usage:

```
public class UserController : BaseController<User>
    {
        public UserController(IUserService service)
        {
            Service = service;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the class that is implementing IUserService?

Comment: @Dismissile, I updated my question with classes. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue with initializing a dummy class from services assembly in the Application_Start.
the working code looks likes

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {           
        //For IoC Sake!
        var dummyRepository = new DummyRepository();
        var dummyService = new DummyService();

        ...
    }
```